# Java Unable to load libary 'tesseract' not found in resource path

Tags: java, tesseract

So i wrote a programm with tesseract and tried to run it on my linux server. I did define where the tessdata is.
But i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (linux-x86-64/libtesseract.so) not found in resource path ([file:/KeywordOCR/KeywordOCR.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at com.krissemicolon.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Comment: How can i install Tess4J? Do i need to install it with my packet manager?

Comment: You don't need to install Test4J, you need to install the missing .so file. Following the answers in the other thread

Comment: Its working thanks